# visual studio 2010 c++ please wait while project information is being collected never closes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm working with new c++ framework ( in this case cocos2d-x ) in visual studio 2010 express 
but when I create a new test project I'm getting this window that says:

"please  wait while project information is being collected"

The problem is that the window never closes and its blocking me from editing the code.
How can I force close it or do any thing about it?
[image]

Comment: this is a new feature of VS

Comment: It's telling you the path (or at least part of it) in which it is searching. Is that path accessible? Are the files perhaps corrupted? Have you tried reinstalling the framework components?